# Android Firebase query return Null

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on a project where there's an activity which contains 3 spinners( Nested). I need the 2nd spinner to have the data based on the selected item of the 1st spinner and the data is retrieved from Firebase

[image]

The 1st spinner is going to have all "Gouv" values , the 2nd one is going to have the "Deleg" values where "Gouv" value is equal to the selected item "Gouv" of the 1st spinner .

Here is the code that i tried and i keep get in the log Null .

```
public class RechCode extends AppCompatActivity {
    DatabaseReference spinnerRef;
    Query spinnerRefG;
    Spinner spinnerG;
    Spinner spinnerD;
    Spinner spinnerL;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapterG;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapterL;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapterD;
    ArrayList<String> spinnerDList;
    ArrayList<String> spinnerGList;
    ArrayList<String> spinnerLOList;
    Query spinnerRefD;
    private String ChoixG;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_rech_code);
        spinnerG = findViewById(R.id.SpinnerGouv);
        spinnerD = findViewById(R.id.SpinnerDeleg);
        spinnerL = findViewById(R.id.SpinnerLoc);
        spinnerRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("CodePostale");
        

        //Query queryD = spinnerG.("state", "CA");
        spinnerGList = new ArrayList<>();
        spinnerDList = new ArrayList<>();
        spinnerLOList = new ArrayList<>();
        adapterD= new ArrayAdapter<String>( RechCode.this, android.R. layout. simple_spinner_dropdown_item,spinnerDList);
        adapterL= new ArrayAdapter<String>( RechCode.this, android.R. layout. simple_spinner_dropdown_item,spinnerLOList);
        adapterG= new ArrayAdapter<String>( RechCode.this, android.R. layout. simple_spinner_dropdown_item,spinnerGList);
        spinnerG.setAdapter(adapterG);
        spinnerD.setAdapter(adapterD);
        spinnerL.setAdapter(adapterL);
        ShowdataGouv();
        spinnerRefG= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("CodePostale").child("Deleg").orderByChild("Gouv").equalTo(ChoixG);

        ShowdataDeleg();
        spinnerG.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {


            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                ChoixG = spinnerGList.get(i);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gouvernorat:" + ChoixG, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {}
        });



        Button retour = (Button) findViewById(R.id.return_btn);

        retour.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                RetourMenu();
            }
        });




    }


    private void ShowdataLoc(String text) {
        spinnerRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot1) {
                for (DataSnapshot item:snapshot1.getChildren()){
                    spinnerLOList.add(item.child("Loc").getValue().toString());

                }
                adapterD.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void ShowdataDeleg() {
        spinnerRefG.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot2) {
                for (DataSnapshot item:snapshot2.getChildren()){
                    spinnerDList.add(item.child("Deleg").getValue().toString());


                }
                Log.d("Value","BBBBBBBB"+ snapshot2);
                adapterD.notifyDataSetChanged();


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void ShowdataGouv() {
        spinnerRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot3) {
                for (DataSnapshot item:snapshot3.getChildren()){
                    spinnerGList.add(item.child("Gouv").getValue().toString());
                    Log.d("Value","AAAAAAAAA"+ snapshot3);

                }
                adapterG.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }


    private void RetourMenu() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Menus.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the way you construct the query here:

```
spinnerRefG= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
    .getReference("CodePostale")
    .child("Deleg")
    .orderByChild("Gouv")
    .equalTo(ChoixG);
```

You're asking to load child nodes of `/CodePostale/Deleg` that have a `Gouv` property with a value of `ChoixG`. But if we check the screenshot of the data, there is no `/CodePostale/Deleg`, so no data is returned.

What you want instead is to check the child nodes of `/CodePostale` and return the ones where their `Deleg/Gouv` property has a value of `ChoixG`, which you can do with:

```
spinnerRefG= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
    .getReference("CodePostale")
    .orderByChild("Deleg/Gouv")
    .equalTo(ChoixG);
```